# Hide MySite, Newsfeed and OneDrive for Extranet user

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

How does everyone approach the situation where Extranet users attempt to follow the site or clicking on the user name to go to user profile, and MySite is not enabled for them?

One scenario is Extranet user clicking on the "FOLLOW" on the top right hand corner, and it'll take them to MySite asking for AD username and password. I already informed the MySite section is not for external user, however, i would like to disable some of those functions for Extranet users to avoid confusions.

[image]

Much appreciated!